# vlc import error in python script + ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: python, libvlc

I want to import the vlc from my python script, but it is getting error like follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in 
    import vlc
ImportError: No module named vlc

How to solve this problem??

Answer (score 1):

For people stumbling upon this answer in 2020 and using *Debian Linux*, try the following command:

`sudo pip3 install python-vlc`

Answer (score 0):

looks like your files are not on "sys.path", from where usually python tries to pick up imports

Try and access from interpreter. just type "import vlc" and see if that works.

If it does't work then just copy your vlc module files (I guess its vlc.py) to your python sys.path location and try again

go through these links, it may help

https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path

Comment: How to get that vlc module files in ubuntu? I tried to import vlc but it is showing same error. There is no file like vlc.py how to get it......

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pip install python-vlc in command prompt (if you are using windows). This will remove that error, as vlc is not yet installed on your system.
If you are using Ubuntu or other Linux Kernel OS, then first install pip (and python) on your system using whatever your package manager is (if necessary), then do pip install python-vlc.